# When does неделя become неделю?

Tags: существительные

I've seen неделю, but I don't know of when the transformation occurs. Could somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 5):

**Неделю** is the accusative singular. The ending comes from a Proto-Slavic nasal — **nedělj**ǫ*** — which is a cognate of the accusative ending **-am** of the Latin first declension, e. g. *agricol**am** vidi* "I saw a farmer [*agricola*]". The ancient Slavs kind of Frenchified that *[am]* to a twangy *[oⁿ]*, which then lost its twang and became a clear *[u]* in Russian.

And that Latin example shows you the basic usage of accusative: it's the direct object case. E. g. *Вот как я провёл эту неделю* "That's how I've spent this week."

The accusative is also the case used with certain prepositions; the logic of which prepositions take which cases is old and often unclear, so no examples, to keep this simple. You'll come to that eventually.

Finally, since *неделя* is a word for a period of time, its accusative has another important usage — it means "for [the duration of] a week". Just like **минуту** can mean "for a minute", and **год** means "year" but can also mean "for a year" (since its accusative happens to have the same form as its nominative.)

Comment: This was very helpful. Could you provide to me an example in which the accusative case is used with certain prepositions?

Comment: @ShadowMecc If we stick with the word: **два раза в неделю** "twice a week", **за неделю до отъезда** "a week before departure", **отправиться на неделю в Кострому** "to go to Kostroma for a week" (two prepositioned accusatives there).

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I do not know of how to figure out when the object of the preposition should be in the accusative form. Could you explain this?

Comment: @ShadowMecc generally, it's used with prepositions of location, replacing their usual case, when talking about motion towards or into that location. but with notions of time, it's often used for no intuitively discernible reason.

Comment: I thank you for your help. You have allowed for me to gain new insight into the matter.

Answer (score 4):

"Неделю" is simply the accusative case of "неделя" (week), unless you mean "не делю" which stands for "[I] don't divide". The accusative case itself has too many applications to list it here.

Comment: I understand. If I were to say "I have already studied Russian for two weeks", should I say "Я уже учу русский язык две неделе"?

Comment: "Я учу русский язык уже две неделИ (целую неделЮ)."

Comment: @ShadowMecc Plural differs from singular. Both nominative and accusative plural are "недели". Thus "_for one week_" = "_одну неделю_" and "_for two weeks_" = "_две недели_". But note that for numbers 5..20 genitive case must be used: "_for five weeks_" = "_пять недель_". This is due to the older singular-dual-plural system.

Comment: @Alex_ander, which one is correct? I have referenced the prepositional case in Russian and have found that the proper ending-change for feminine nouns that end in "я" is "е"

Comment: @ShadowMecc There's no Prepositional here. Singular "Неделю" vs Plural(Dual) "Недели" vs Plural "Недель".

Comment: @ShadowMecc Prepositional case would give different meaning and point at a particular week (not number of weeks): "на этой (прошлой, следующей) неделе" -> 'this (last, next) week'.

Comment: I think I understand what you both mean, but I want to make sure. What case should one use for "неделя" in a sentence like "I have studied for two weeks"? I at first had thought that it should be the nominative plural, but I now think that it should be the accusative plural. Could somebody elaborate on this?

Comment: @ShadowMecc Simply recall that Nominative case is reserved exclusively for subjects and predicatives.

Comment: Alright. I will remember that. What case should one ue for "неделя" in a sentence like "I have studied for two weeks"?

Comment: @ShadowMecc Accusative.

Comment: I understand why one should use the Accusative case for such situations, now. I thank you for your help.